# IntelliJ warning: Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, mockito

IntelliJ Idea is giving following warning for one of the statements in my test cases.

> **Warning: Unchecked generics array creation for varargs parameter**
>
> Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler

All I am doing is :

`when(someService.someMethod(id)).thenThrow(AccountNotFoundException.class)`

Comment: It would be easier if more context is provided, e.g. the signature of the mocked method or declaration of passed argument.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A better way to accomplish that would probably be:

```
when(someService.someMethod(id)).thenThrow(new AccountNotFoundException());
```

then the compiler should infer the type correctly.

If `someService.someMethod(id)` has return type `void` you can do:

```
doThrow(new AccountNotFoundException()).when(someService).someMethod(id);
```

Please refer to the [official Mockito documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html) for examples like this using `thenThrow`. The documentation is very clear on this point.

You can also check the following StackOverflow question which is very similar (if not an exact duplicate):

[How to mock and assert a thrown exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243580/mockito-how-to-mock-and-assert-a-thrown-exception)