# How i can stop call a method void with mockito?

Tags: java, mockito

When I invoke the functions method from a Test class, I want the executeSol method not to run because it causes me errors.

```
public String funciones(String arguments){
    //Many operations . . . 
    animalInterface.executeSol(integer id, String msg); <-- void 
  return soluciones;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you're trying to achieve? What should be the result?

Comment: No idea what do you want.

Comment: *I have a void method into another method* No you don't and no you cannot.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: sorry for my english. I will explain with steps:

Comment: It sounds like you want to stub the second method.  Is it in the same class as the first method, to be called on the same object?  Or are you calling it on a different object?

Comment: I downvoted because the question is unclear and the code posted has syntax errors. Please call me with @jannis once you fix those.

Comment: The idea is to know if, it is possible to prevent the line of the void method from being executed, using Mockito for that @jannis

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, https://gist.github.com/mariuszs/7489190
There is a great example on how to test for an exception. 
This was asked previously. 
[Mockito How to mock and assert a thrown exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243580/mockito-how-to-mock-and-assert-a-thrown-exception)