# I couldn't understand the logic of willThrow, doThrow in junit mockito testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit

I have this piece of simple code but couldn't understand its logic and meaning.

```
void findByIdThrows(){
    given(addressRepository.findById(1)).willThrow(new RuntimeException("boom iii"));

    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> servic.findById(1));

    then(addressRepository).should().findById(1);
}
```

Does it mean: if you got a RuntimeException during the finding of the address with id #1 then assert that I'll give the RuntimeException?

What does the last line (then....) do exactly?

Comment: I recommend reading a tutorial on `bdd-mockito`, e.g. [this one on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/bdd-mockito).

Comment: I saw the link. That's a useful reference. Thanks for sharing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-st line:

define call `addressRepository.findById(1)` will throw `RuntimeException`

2-st line:

checks if `servic.findById(1)` throws `RuntimeException`

3-th line:

equivalent of:

```
 verify(addressRepository).findById(1)
```

And checks if the `addressRepository.findById(1)` was called

Comment: I called addressRepository.findById(1) at first line. Why should I verify calling of this method again?

Comment: Because the first line just sets up the mock, so that _if_ the call occurs, then the exception will be thrown.  The third line checks whether the call really did occur.

Comment: You wasn't call `addressRepository.findById(1)` in first line - there you say to Mokito thats when somewhere in the test process will be called `addressRepository.findById(1)` then it throws exception

Comment: Thanks dawood-ibn-kareem  and Даниил Дмитроченков. Now these lines are meaningful for me.

Comment: When I change the id number from 1 to 2 at first line, I expect that test be  failed but test passed with no errors. Why this happened? I Mocked it with id #1.

Comment: void findByIdThrows(){
        given(addressRepository.findById(2)).willThrow(new RuntimeException("boom iii"));

        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> servic.findById(1));

        then(addressRepository).should().findById(anyInt());
    }

In this test I changed the given id to 2 but test didn't give any error.

Comment: probably this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243580/mockito-how-to-mock-and-assert-a-thrown-exception