# Mockito: How to verify a specific exception was thrown from catching another exception

Tags: java, exception, mockito

Example:

```
public T f1() {
  try{
    Object o = new Object();
    
    o.someFunc() // i want to mock this function call to throw an exception (ex) Exception1)

  }
  catch (Exception1 e) {
      throw new Exception2() 
 }
```

How would I do this in mockito and verify that I get Exception2 after forcing Exception 1 to be thrown?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito How to mock and assert a thrown exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243580/mockito-how-to-mock-and-assert-a-thrown-exception)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when` and `thenThrow` to mocke `Exeption1` from `someFunc`

```
when(someService.someFunction("param1", "param12")).thenThrow( new Exception1());
```

then `f1()` should catch exception and throw `Exception2`

you can assert exception class Name as below,

```
assertEquals(mvcResult.getResolvedException().getClass().getName(), "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException");
```