# Mockito Test cases for catch block with Exception

Tags: mockito, junit5

Class A

```
{
    public String name (String str)
    {
        try {
            fullName = str + "org";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug(e.getMessage())
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito How to mock and assert a thrown exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243580/mockito-how-to-mock-and-assert-a-thrown-exception)

Comment: and this code can't be compiled, and in case you declared `fullName` somewhere, the code `fullName = str + "org"` won't throw any exception :))